# How do I run the latest version of rsync as root with SimpleSSHD?

Tags: ssh, rsync

SimpleSSHD is a free (open source, no ads) SSH server based on dropbear that supports scp, sftp, and rsync.

How do I run the latest version of `rsync` as root when accessing my phone from a remote host?

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest `rsync` binary:

```
mkdir ~/bin && cd ~/bin &&
curl --progress-bar -L -o rsync "https://github.com/JBBgameich/rsync-static/releases/download/continuous/rsync-aarch64" &&
chmod 755 rsync && echo 'export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH' > ~/.profile
```

To then use the new downloaded version of `rsync` as `root` on the Android phone, use the following `rsync` command options **from the remote host**:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 2222' --rsync-path='su -c /data/user/0/org.galexander.sshd/files/bin/rsync'
```

You'll need to add the source and destination and other `rsync` options. See the man page for what these listed options are doing :)